Why do I have secondary IP addresses and APIPA addresses?
I'm trying to configure my network interfaces on an ubuntu 22.04 server, but I'm running into problem concerning the ips that are assigned.
The server is a Dell R330 with dual onboard Broadcom BCM5720 NICs and I added an Intel I350-T4 card from Dell (secondhand, but genuine Dell/Intel part). So the server have a total of 6 NICs.
The purpose of this server is to be a virtualization host.
I have to say, I'm pretty new in modern linux systems, but I managed to install everything properly, but facing a problem concerning ip configuration.
So I used netplan to configure the interfaces like this (I tried to keep the network simple):
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses:
        - 192.168.10.55/24
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.10.254
      nameservers:
        addresses: [194.2.0.20, 8.8.8.8]
    eno2:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses:
        - 192.168.10.41/24
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.10.254
      nameservers:
        addresses: [194.2.0.20, 8.8.8.8]
    enp2s0f0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses:
        - 192.168.10.56/24
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.10.254
      nameservers:
        addresses: [194.2.0.20, 8.8.8.8]
    enp2s0f1:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses:
        - 192.168.10.57/24
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.10.254
      nameservers:
        addresses: [194.2.0.20, 8.8.8.8]
    enp2s0f2:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses:
        - 192.168.10.58/24
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.10.254
      nameservers:
        addresses: [194.2.0.20, 8.8.8.8]
    enp2s0f3:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses:
        - 192.168.10.59/24
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.10.254
      nameservers:
        addresses: [194.2.0.20, 8.8.8.8]

But when I do a ip a I get :
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b4:96:91:bd:94:44 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.10.56/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global enp2s0f0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.10.184/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global secondary enp2s0f0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::b696:91ff:febd:9444/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 10:98:36:a9:e1:c5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp4s0f0
    inet 192.168.10.55/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.10.181/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global secondary eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::1298:36ff:fea9:e1c5/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 10:98:36:a9:e1:c6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp4s0f1
    inet 192.168.10.41/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global eno2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.10.182/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global secondary eno2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::1298:36ff:fea9:e1c6/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: enp2s0f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b4:96:91:bd:94:45 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.10.57/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global enp2s0f1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 169.254.226.157/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global enp2s0f1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::b696:91ff:febd:9445/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: enp2s0f2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b4:96:91:bd:94:46 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.10.58/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global enp2s0f2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 169.254.181.188/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global enp2s0f2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::b696:91ff:febd:9446/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: enp2s0f3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b4:96:91:bd:94:47 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.10.59/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global enp2s0f3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 169.254.18.189/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global enp2s0f3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::b696:91ff:febd:9447/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:cf:6e:36 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

As you can see the netplan is applied, but for some interfaces I have a secondary ip attributed by DHCP (by a cisco asa) and for the other interfaces there is an APIPA secondary address (but not with the key word secondary) attributed.
I don't understand why the DHCP server is attributing secondary addresses and furthermore I don't understand why the last 3 NICs of the I350-T4 board received APIPA addresses.
Sure I did something wrong, but I can't put my finger on it.
Can you please advise me and help me?
(sorry for my average English)
Edit: I think it worth mentioning that before I used netplan, the secondary ips were assigned as primaries in the same manner (DHCP for the first 3 NICs and APIPA for the last 3 NICs) and it was already weird. That's why I tried to use netplan to configure all the interfaces.
Edit: I found the problem, look at my answer
Thank's mpboden for trying to help !
Bless all.

Please confirm that this is a Server installation and not a Desktop installation. Do you have more than one .yaml config file in /etc/netplan/? What is output of ls /etc/systemd/network?

@mpboden Hello, thanks for your comment.
Yes, it is a server installation and I have only one .yaml config file in /etc/netplan/.
Concerning the output of ls /etc/systemd/network, there is nothing there.

@mpboden To clarify: Cloud-init is active on that server so at first there was the 50-cloud-init.yaml file and I created another .yaml config file to configure my interfaces. But along my search I saw that it could be an issue, so I tried to disable cloud-init's network configuration by writing the file /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg containing network: {config: disabled} like advised in the /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml file and I put my netplan config in /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml file (deleting my custom one).

I found the problem, shame on me I didn't see it earlier.
I did install LXQt to have a minimal graphical environment to be able to use virt-manager to ease the virtual machines configurations.
The thing is, LXQt uses connman to configure the network and when I realized that, I took a look at it and I saw there was an active configuration on my ethernet interfaces, including active DHCP on every interface. So that was conflicting with my netplan configuration. I just deleted my .yaml config file and did my network configuration with connman. Everything is working as expected now !
